# Smallest element in a Linked List in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list of 10 unordered integers, output the list, then find the smallest element in the list and output it. This is what I have. It finds and output an element but not the smallest in the list. Please help.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

public class intergers
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList <Integer> integers = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        //Generates an unordered list of ten integers.
        Random Doge = new Random();


        //Using a for loop.

        for(int count =0; count<10; count++)
        {
            int integer = Doge.nextInt(10);
            integers.add(integer);
        }
        if(integers.getLast() !=0)
        {
            integers.removeLast();
            integers.add(0);
        }

        System.out.println(integers); //Prints out that list.
        int Oedipus; 
        for(Oedipus =0; Oedipus <integers.size()-1; Oedipus++)
        {
            if(integers.get(Oedipus) < integers.get(Oedipus++))
            {
                //int smallest = integers.get(Oedipus);
                int smallest = integers.get(Oedipus);
            }

            if(integers.get(Oedipus) > integers.get(Oedipus++))
            {
                //int smallest = integers.get(Oedipus);
                //System.out.println("Smallest " + integers.get(Oedipus));
            }
            int smallest = integers.size();
        }
        int smallest = integers.get(Oedipus);
        System.out.println("The smallest element is: " + smallest);

    }
}
```

Comment: Help with what? What is your question? Have you tried a _debugger_?

Comment: `Random Doge = new Random();` I like it.

Comment: This Doge: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doge_of_Venice or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doge_(meme)? Archer put my curiosity here.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger as this will give you a better understanding of what your code is actually doing.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the Collections.min() method?

Comment: That doesn't look like it is a thing. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Comment: @Pat Collection != Collections. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: `LinkedList` implements `Collection` which is what `Collections.min(Collection<? extends T> coll, Comparator<? super T> comp)` want. Collections is just a "helper" class.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
System.out.println(integers); //Prints out that list.
```

does not do what the comment says it does. Add a loop to go through the items, and print each item individually to see what's in the list.

Your lines that deal with `smallest`, e.g. this one

```
int smallest = integers.get(Oedipus);
```

are incorrect for two reasons: they declare a new `smallest` every time in a nested scope, and they do not initialize `smallest` to begin with.

To fix this, declare `smallest` outside the loop, initialize it with the initial element of the list, and then iterate elements starting from `1`, comparing it to `smallest`. Alternatively, store the *index*, not the value, of the smallest element in the `smallest`. Initialize it with zero, and set it to `Oedipus` if you find an element that is smaller than the one at `integers.get(smallest)`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate through the list and try to find the minimum element.

```
int minInt = Integer.MAX_VALUE
for(int i = 0; i < Integers.size(), ++i){
    if(Integers.get(i) < minInt)
        minInt = Integers.get(i)
}
```

**Edit:** The reason I stored the value rather than the index is because random access of linked lists is slow. If it was an array then random access would be fast.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to removing the unnecessary declarations of `smallest`, you are also resetting `smallest` to the size of the LinkedList every time that you iterate through with your `int smallest = integers.size();` code.  You should remove this along with the code at the end that states:

```
int smallest = integers.get(Oedipus);
System.out.println("The smallest element is: " + smallest);
```

All this does is it redefines `smallest` as the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is somewhat strange. Also you should consider the scope of variables. the "smallest" variables that you have through your code are different.

Analyze the following redefined function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    LinkedList <Integer> integers = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    //Generates an unordered list of ten integers.
    Random Doge = new Random();

    //Using a for loop.
    for(int count =0; count<10; count++)
    {
        int integer = Doge.nextInt(10);
        integers.add(integer);
    }

    int smallest = integers.get(0);
    System.out.println(integers); //Prints out that list.
    for( int Oedipus =1; Oedipus <integers.size()-1; Oedipus++)
    {
        if(integers.get(Oedipus) < smallest )
        {
            //int smallest = integers.get(Oedipus);
            smallest = integers.get(Oedipus);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The smallest element is: " + smallest);     
}
```